# I want to insert values for 3 columns in a teradata view .But it gives errors Syntax looks correct but error is not related to syntax

Tags: sql, teradata

```
INSERT INTO
sample_db.sample_table(CONFRM_CD_VAL_TXT,CONFRM_CDSET_NM,SRC_CD_VAL_TXT,CHNL_SRC_CD)
values ("CAD","CLM_MEDIA_TY_CD","CAD","ESI" );
```

Here I get a error as

> Column CAD not found in sample_db.sample_table.
> Elapsed time = 00:00:00.032

Comment: `"` means you are referencing a column. `'` means you want a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace double quotes `""` (refers to columns) with single quotes `''` (refers to strings).

```
INSERT INTO
sample_db.sample_table(CONFRM_CD_VAL_TXT,CONFRM_CDSET_NM,SRC_CD_VAL_TXT,CHNL_SRC_CD)
values ('CAD','CLM_MEDIA_TY_CD','CAD','ESI');
```

Comment: Double quotes are for all delimited identifiers, i.e. both columns and others.